# DataGridCell empty set DbNull.value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am populating a datagrid with a dataset and `I have my dataset verified for nullable values` -

My problem is :

When the dataset is validating, it **found *empty rows* and the errors are not displayed**. 
I would like to define the empty cells with a DBNull.value. Is there any way to do it ?. 
I have found a property named `TargetNullValue` that could work ?

Comment: Empty `rows` or Empty `columns` ?

Comment: Empty cells I meand when the datagrid is populated and some field has empty string as value

Comment: Why don't you add IS_NULL in your SQL such that those fields then become bindable  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it, by making a convertion

```
 public class ConvertStringToDBNull : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cufo)
    {

        if (value is string)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == string.Empty)
            {
                return DBNull.Value;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cufo)
    {

        if (value is string)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == string.Empty)
            {
                return DBNull.Value;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```