# DataGrid won't allow me to remove values after entering some

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable` which when the program is first started is empty, if the user is to add a value it is written to the appropriate `DataTable` cell as it should.

However if the user is the remove this value, the `DataGrid` will not allow it and will not update the `DataTable`, like so:

[image]

I can not seem to find anything online about this and not sure if it is to do with the `DataGrid` or the `DataTable`, any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Here is one solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156731/how-do-i-get-a-wpf-datagrid-to-save-changes-back-to-the-database I hope this helps

Comment: Is it because it's trying to set a .NET `null` to the table, but it really wants a `DbNull.Value`?

Comment: @DonBoitnott yeah that definitely sounds like a possible cause of the issue, do you know how I could go about assigning `DbNull.Value` to the `DataTable` if the user has entered a .NET `null` value?

Comment: You'd probably have to be using a `Converter` on the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and apply a converter to the bindings:

```
private static readonly ConvertStringToDBNull _converter = new ConvertStringToDBNull();
private void dgDt_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    ((DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column).Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { Converter = _converter };
}
```

You will find a sample implementation of a converter that converts between `string.Empty` and `DBNull.Value` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247200/datagridcell-empty-set-dbnull-value).

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your binding for read and write, set the binding Mode=Twoway.

Comment: It is currently a two way binding